# Spark & Python 2.7 - Complicated Data Structure - GroupByKey

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an rdd that looks like this:

```
totalsrdd = [((2, 16),[[1,2,3,...,36],[2,2,3,...,36]]),((2,17),[[1,2,3,...,36]]),...]
```

The keys are the days (2,16) etc. and they each correspond to a list or multiple lists of 36 numbers. For each date, I need one list where the ith entry in the list is the average of the ith entry in each list or lists for a respective date.

For example, for (2,16), the average for the first entry would be (1+2)/(36+36) or .04166 since there are two lists for that date.

```
newRdd = [((2,16),[[.04166,.055555,.083333,...,1]]),(2,17),[[.027777,.055555,.083333,...,1]]),...]
```

Since there is only one list for (2,17), each entry in the list is divided by 36.

This is the code I have so far. The data is much bigger than just two dates.

```
def get_partition(x):
    j = [(x[1][i]).total_seconds() for i in range(len(x[1]))]
    return (x[0],j)
newTimeDeltaRdd2 = newtimeDeltaRdd.map(lambda x : ((x[1].month,x[1].day), x[0]))
totals = newTimeDeltaRdd2.map(lambda x: (get_partition(x)))
totalsrdd = totals.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1])))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to convert totalsrdd to a dictionary? that would make this much easier.

Comment: You might want to edit the operation `1+2/36+36` to `(1+2)/(36+36)`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but wouldn't `newrdd = totalsrdd.mapValues(lambda l: [sum(x)/len(l) for x in zip(*l)])` do the job?

Comment: Or `/(len(l)*36))` for your definition of average, which I don't quite understand. `(1+2)/2` would be the normal definition of average.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution to get `newrdd`:

```
totalsrdd = [((2, 16),[[1,2,3,...,36],[2,2,3,...,36]]),((2,17),[[1,2,3,...,36]]),...]

newrdd = []
for key, _list in totalsrdd:
    averages = []
    for i in range(36):
        averages.append(sum([_l[i] for _l in _list]) / 36 * len(_list))
    newrdd.append((key, averages))
```

Comment: Answer shouldn't be without explanation - please edit your answer and add explanation what is changed and why

Comment: I receive an error saying 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution that will give the behavior you described.

I would still consider using a dictionary

```
import numpy as np
for entry in totalsrdd:
    sum = np.zeros(36)
    for ls in entry[1]:
        sum = np.add(sum, ls)
    sum = np.divide(sum, len(entry[1]) * 36)
    entry[1] = sum
```

Comment: This updates totalsrdd in place. It would be a minor edit to get it to create `newrdd`.

Comment: I receive an error saying 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable